# Entity Framework : Fluent API makes duplicate foreign keys in one to zero or one

Tags: c#, entity, fluent

I have some models and I want to have a "**One to zero or one**" association.
I searched and tried to make the association using Fluent API.
 Here are my classes :

```
public partial class Bill
{

[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
[Required]
public double Amount { get; set; }

public virtual DomainRegOrder DomainRegOrder { get; set; }

}

public partial class DomainRegOrder
{
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
[Required]
public string DomainName { get; set; }

public virtual Bill Bill { get; set; }
}
```

and in the my DataContext class :

```
public class DataContext : DbContext {

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

 modelBuilder.Entity<DomainRegOrder>()
 .HasOptional(x => x.Bill)
 .WithOptionalDependent();

 }
```

but when I Initialize the Database, in the **Bills** table, I will have two 
columns named "**DomainRegOrder_Id**" and "**DomainRegOrder_Id1**".

I tried to add the **DomainRegOrderId** in the **Bill** entity as bellow:

```
public int? DomainRegOrderId { get; set; }
```

But there will be a "**DomainRegOrderId**"  and  a "**DomainRegOrder_Id**" on the "Bills" table.

I also changed **.WithOptionalDependent()** to **.WithOptionalPrincipal()**
but no changes were made as far as I know!!

Would somebody help me to get rid of these duplicate foreign keys, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Bill>() 
  .HasOptional(x => x.DomainRegOrder) 
  .WithOptionalDependent(c => c.Bill).Map(p => p.MapKey("DomainRegOrderID");
```

Comment: And after I tried that I got error 0019: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name '____' was already defined. It seems like MapKey wants to create it's own key.